# Error while building react native app - Deprecated API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build, expo, build.gradle

I'm trying to build my expo app so while building I had some errors. someone have an idea about this issue.

> [stderr]  Note:
> /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. [stderr]  Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. [stderr]  Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations. [stderr]  Note:
> /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/checkbox/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/checkbox/ReactCheckBoxEvent.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. [stderr]  Note:
> /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-notifications/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/notifications/notifications/presentation/builders/ExpoNotificationBuilder.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Answer (score 0):

As you will see in [Expo's documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting/#build-errors), about errors like yours:

> Regardless of the phase, it's common to see log entries prefixed with
> [stderr], but keep in mind that this doesn't necessarily mean those
> logs point to errors; it's common for CLI tools to use stderr to
> output warnings and other diagnostics.

The example given in the link happens to be about @react-native-async-storage, and clarifies that it did not cause the failed build.